# Units of a finite commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unity and $p$ a prime integer.

Suppose that there is a primitive $p$th root of unity $u \in R$ such that $u - 1$ is a unit.

Is it true that $u^i - 1$ is also a unit for all $1 \leq i \leq p - 1$? and how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is always the case is $u-1$ and $u^i-1$ generate the same ideal:
$$u^i-1=(u-1)(u^{i-1}+\cdots+u+1)$$
and
$$u-1=(u^i-1)(u^{i(j-1)}+\cdots+u^i+1)$$
where $ij\equiv1\pmod p$. If then $u-1$ is a unit, then $(u-1)R=R$
and so $(u^i-1)R=R$. Then $u^i-1$ is a unit.